# Springboot3.2.0 occurred (Java. util. LinkedHashMap is in module Java. base of loader 'bootstrap')

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, java-17

Using webflux, data objects inherit a parent class and implement an interface. Everything runs normally in version 3.1.6, but after upgrading to 3.2.0, it occurs in Flux.freeIterable.flatMap (Java. util. LinkedHashMap is in module Java. base of loader 'bootstrap'). I would like to know what caused this to happen in 3.2.0

I have tried JSON conversion and hope you can provide me with some ideas

Comment: Nothing in your description suggests a particular issue with your code. Can you provide more information, typically enough for us to reproduce the problem? Minimal code snippets showing your controller and DTO classes, your build file, a complete stacktrace with the error.